# How to prevent Server Manager from appearing when logging in in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, startup, windows

I almost never use this app and it always opens when I login.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a checkbox at the root level of the Server Manager that says "do not show me this console at logon" - check it, and then close Server Manager.

You need to do this for each account you log onto the server with, and for each server you logon to.